# In Neal Stephenson's Snow Crash, what other biblical stories besides Babel does he symbolize or reference?

Tags: neal-stephenson, snow-crash

I understand the Babel reference but am blind to the others. I'm not too familiar with the Bible. Thanks guys

Comment: Do you mean specifically, literally, *only* references that are in one or more of the various versions of the Christian Bible? There are so very many *historical* references in Snow Crash, but not all of them are part of the Christian traditions.

Comment: It borrows from Sumerian myths (Enki, Innana), the Christina Bible and possible others.

Comment: This might answer your rather broad question: [Comments on Snow Crash Theology by Russell M. Taylor Research - Professor of Computer Science, Physics & Astronomy, and Applied Physical Sciences at the University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~taylorr/snowcrash.html)

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza, you should make that an answer; I can't imagine a more orderly catalog of biblical references in Snow Crash is going to stumble along.

Answer (score 4):

This article might hold the answers you're looking for: [Comments on Snow Crash Theology by Russell M. Taylor](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~taylorr/snowcrash.html)

[image]

Russell Taylor is a Research Professor of Computer Science, Physics & Astronomy, and Applied Physical Sciences at the University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill.  He is the co-director of the UNC NIH National Research Resource for Computer Integrated Systems for Microscopy and Manipulation.

Enthralled by the plot and disturbed by the references to Christianity that were peppered throughout [Snow Crash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash) he set out to investigate them.